# Redbean php multiple many-to-many relations to same table

Tags: php, database, orm, relationship, redbean

Here is my situation: user have list of liked objects and list of disliked.
I want to act like this:

```
list($cat, $dog) = R::dispense('object', 2);
$user->sharedLikedobjectsList[] = $cat;
$user->sharedDislikedobjectsList[] = $dog;
```

But afterall RedbeanPhp creates single tabe (object_user) with 2 rows inside.
What shall I do to have 2 different tables and accessible properties on $user bean?

Answer (score 0):

use $bean->link() method to create an alias name for your foreign key table.

such as this :

```
$user->link("pet",array("some_prop"=>"some_value"))->sharedPet = dog;
```